# Duplicate data when insert to DB through form

Tags: php, mysql

The problem is when my script inserts it duplicates the data; like in this photo its added 2 times in Database:

MySQL table:

[image: mysql table]

Page:

[image: page]

On submit it redirects to `menu_submit`, when the insert is done it redirects to create_menu.php

Here is menu_submit.php

```
<?php

include ("../include/layout/header.php");
include ("../include/check_connection.php");
include ("../include/check_page.php");

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $menu_name = $_POST["menu"];
    $optradio_choise = (int)$_POST["optradio"];
    $rank_name = (int)$_POST["rank"];
    $menu_name2 = mysqli_real_escape_String($conn,$menu_name);
    $query = "
        INSERT INTO `website_navbar` (
            `item_name`,
            `rank`,
            `visible`
        ) VALUES (
            '{$menu_name}',
            '{$rank_name}',
            {$optradio_choise}
        )
    ";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if(mysqli_query($conn, $query) && mysqli_affected_rows($conn)) {
        echo "Menu add sucessfully";
        redirect1("mange_content.php");
    }
}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: `redirect1("mange_content.php");` remove 1 from `redirect1`

Comment: You're executing the query twice.  So it's being executed twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    if(mysqli_query($conn,$query) && mysqli_affected_rows($conn)){
```

Did you spot call to `mysqli_query` **twice** ?

Answer (score 0):

you write `mysqli_query two times` thats why your query run two time and it will `insert two record`

```
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
if($result && mysqli_affected_rows($conn)){
     echo "Menu add sucessfully";
     redirect1("mange_content.php");
}
```

so write `$result` instead of `mysqli_query($conn,$query);` in `if condition`